# How can I use PHP functions (Gutenberg WordPress) inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am new at WordPress/Gutenberg, and I am not familiar with PHP. I'm trying to write a custom block with JavaScript in Gutenberg, but I found most of the functions available only work in PHP. How I can use functions in JavaScript like `get_post_meta()` , or `get_the_tags()`

Comment: You can't.. these functions are written in and for PHP which is processed on the server side, while javascript is processed on the client side. You will need to write some PHP that exposes the data to Javascript most likely via an api/ajax call

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PHP functions can be used inside Gutenberg blocks by creating a dynamic block which calls a PHP function to render the content. This enables use of all the available PHP & WordPress functions like `get_post_meta()` etc.

The [Developer documentation has an example block code](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) that shows how this is implemented and is a great place to get started. Also, the [`<ServerSideRender>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-server-side-render/) is a useful component that enables rendering of live PHP inside the block editor.

Reviewing the source code of an existing core block [(eg. latest posts)](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/latest-posts) that uses PHP to render may also help you get started with building your own block.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i am trying to use this functions on javascript (editor) file .. is there any way to use ? as most of the developers suggest but i am getting an error with <?php ..

Comment: @IrfanAhmed Yes, you need to have the <?php .. function in a php file, then call that php function using `<ServerSideRender>` in JavaScript, in the blocks edit() function (which renders in the javascript editor). Try the example from the docs in my answer to see how it all connects together.

Comment: it should be noted that Wordpress recommends using native rendering with JS over <ServerSideRender> - partly due to the fact that it genreally is slower.
However nothing wrong in using it for some blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround since PHP outputs text you can use it to write Javascript code that will be executed on the page load or triggered by an event. Just don't forget to surround your js code with script tags